# Why does my if statement always evaluate to true?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I need to go through the months of the year and find out if the last day of the month is 28, 29, 30 or 31. My problem is that the first if statement always evaluates to true:

```
MOIS_I = 31
if (mois == "Janvier" || "Mars" || "Mai" || "Juillet" || "Août" || "Octobre" || "Décembre" || "1" || "3" || "5" || "7" || "8" || "10" || "12" || "01" || "03" || "05" || "07" || "08") {
            window.alert("Le mois " + mois + " de l'année " + annee + " compte " + MOIS_I + " jours ");
}
```

Also, it seems like it is necessary to do `if (mois == "Janver" || mois == "Février" || ... )` and so on, but I wanted to know if there was a better way to do it.

Here is the full code:

```
    var mois, annee, test4, test100, test400;
    const MOIS_P = 30;
    const MOIS_I = 31;
    const FEV_NORM = 28; 
    const FEV_BISSEX = 29;
    const TEST_4 = 4;
    const TEST_100 = 100;
    const TEST_400 = 400;

    mois = window.prompt("Entrez un mois de l'année", "");
    annee = window.prompt("Entrez l'année de ce mois", "");
    /* MOIS IMPAIRS */
    if (mois == "Janvier" || "Mars" || "Mai" || "Juillet" || "Août" || "Octobre" || "Décembre" || "1" || "3" || "5" || "7" || "8" || "10" || "12" || "01" || "03" || "05" || "07" || "08") {
            window.alert("Le mois " + mois + " de l'année " + annee + " compte " + MOIS_I + " jours ");
    /* MOIS PAIRS */
    } else if (mois == "Février" || "Avril" || "Juin" || "Septembre" || "Novembre" || "2" || "4" || "6" || "9" || "11" || "02" || "04" || "06" || "09") { 
        if (mois == "Février") {
            test4 = parseInt(annee) % TEST_4;
            test100 = parseInt(annee) % TEST_100;
            test400 = parseInt(annee) % TEST_400;
            if (test4 == 0) {
                if (test100 != 0) {
                    window.alert("Le mois " + mois + " de l'année " + annee + " compte " + FEV_BISSEX + " jours ");
                } else {
                    window.alert("Le mois " + mois + " de l'année " + annee + " compte " + FEV_NORM + " jours ");
                }
            } else if (test400 == 0) {
                    window.alert("Le mois " + mois + " de l'année " + annee + " compte " + FEV_BISSEX + " jours ");
            } else {
                window.alert("Le mois " + mois + " de l'année " + annee + " compte " + FEV_NORM + " jours ");
            }
        } else {
            window.alert("Le mois " + mois + " de l'année " + annee + " compte " + MOIS_P + " jours ");
        }           
    } else {
        window.alert("Apocalypse!");
    }
```

TEST_4, TEST_100, TEST_400 are to test if the year is a leap year (which means february has 29 days instead of 28).

Thank you!

Comment: What language? It *kind of matters*. Looks like it could be JavaScript, although note that `const` is not (yet) present in standard JavaScript.

Comment: Note that a non-empty string will always evaluate to **true** so `if (/* any condition || */ "Any string here")` will always return **true**. The values **null**, **false** itself, **undefined** and an empty string, however, will evaluate to **false**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of `if` statement, yes, you always need to add `mois ==` part, otherwise you're checking boolean value of string "Fevrier" instead of comparing it to `mois` variable value.

In terms of the general result you're trying to achieve, there are probably a lot of easier ways, available for you in the standard library. If this is JavaScript, see e.g. [this article](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/determining-number-days-month).

Answer (score 2):

do like this (the simple way)

```
var last_day=new Date(year,month,-1).getDate()
```

this will give the last day of month

Comment: It was my first javascript homework, this seems right but i'm not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would go about it:

1. Get month and convert it to a number. You'll probably want to use a hash to do this.
2. Get year and convert it to a number, using `parseInt()` as you have done.
3. If `month % 2 == 1`, then its an odd month:

   - If `year % 400 == 0 || year % 100 == 0 || year % 4 == 0`: handle leap years appropriately.
   - Else: return 30.
4. Else: its an even months, return 31.

Comment: Interesting. I was reading about leap years just a few days ago and I learned something I did not know, so I wanted to share it. An exception is [written in the second paragraph in Wikipedia page for "leap year"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shortening suggestion for your `if()` conditions: **the RegExp Object** (although this will not answer your question).

```
/^(Janvier|Mars|Mai|Juillet|Août|(Octo|Décem)bre|0?[13578]|1[02])$/.test(mois))
// append i after the last forward slash if you want it not to respect case
```

is the same with

```
if (
mois == "Janvier" || mois == "Mars" || mois == "Mai" || mois == "Juillet" ||
mois == "Août" || mois == "Octobre" || mois == "Décembre" || mois == "1" ||
mois == "3" || mois == "5" || mois == "7" || mois == "8" || mois == "10" ||
mois == "12" || mois == "01" || mois == "03" || mois == "05" || mois == "07" ||
mois == "08"
)
```

and

```
if (/^(Février|Avril|Juin|(Sept|Nov)embre|0?[2469]|11)$/.test(mois))
// same thing about the case-insensitive (i) flag here...
```

is the same with

```
if (
mois == "Février" || mois == "Avril" || mois == "Juin" || mois == "Septembre" ||
mois == "Novembre" || mois == "2" || mois == "4" || mois == "6" || mois == "9" ||
mois == "11" || mois == "02" || mois == "04" || mois == "06" || mois == "09"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work without tricky date math:

```
var SomeDate = new Date(2012, 10);  // November, 2012

SomeDate.setDate(SomeDate.getDate() - 1);  // go back one day

var DaysInMonth = SomeDate.getDate();
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a better way to check against a whole bunch of strings.  You put all the allowed names in an object (often called a map) and then you can check to see if the name is in the map with one line of code:

```
var names = {
    "Janvier": true, "Mars": true, "Mai": true, "Juillet": true, 
    "Août": true, "Octobre": true, "Décembre": true, 
    "1": true, "3": true, "5": true, "7": true, "8": true, "10": true, "12": true, 
    "01": true, "03": true, "05": true, "07": true, "08": true
};

if (names[mois] === true) {
     window.alert("Le mois " + mois + " de l'année " + annee + " compte " + MOIS_I + " jours ");
}
```